# Why is no PWM signal generated using Timer 2?

Tags: timers

I managed to work with timer 0 and 1 but am unable to generate a PWM with timer 2 in my atmega328p.

This is the code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* PD6 output */
    DDRD |= (1 << DDD6);

    /* 50% duty cycle */
    OCR2A = 128;

    /* fast PWM  */
    TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21) | (1 << WGM20);

    /* prescaler = 8 */
    TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21);

    while (1);

}
```

Could someone explain what the issue is and why I am not seeing a pwm signal on pin 6 of my arduino uno board?

Thanks

Comment: The post is definitely on topic.  I don't understand why it has attracted a vote to be closed.

Comment: I am the one who up-voted the question, one of the three up-votes for the answer, and just up-voted your comment :)

Comment: It's a shame that multitudes of "leave open" votes don't cancel our erroneous "off-topic" votes. Clearly on-topic. And timers are always such fun! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output compare unit of timer 2 is connected to pins PB3 (OC2A) and PD3 (OC2B). So you have to configure those as outputs.
Keep in mind that you can't choose any pin when using hardware pwm, this hardware feature is linked to specific pins.

You also have to set `COM2A1` in `TCCR2A`. Otherwise `OC2A` is disconnected from the output compare unit (ref: Table 17-3 in [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)).
The effect of `COM2A0/1` depends on the configuration in `WGM20`-`WGM22`.
The same applies to `OC2B` respectively.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but that doesn't seem to work: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/K8KmKnqyvV/

Any suggestions?

Comment: I compiled/flashed your code and I found that in `TCCR2A` you have to set `COM2A1` (see my edit).

Comment: @traducerad: The comment `// enable timer 2` in your code is wrong. It should be `// disable timer 2` in order to be consistent with what the following line actually does.